How to scroll the container when the tracker reaches the end of the screen?
I have an application - Video editor. I load the video into it(timeline) and press play. The video starts playing and the tracker crawls along the container that contains the video. When the tracker reaches the end of the screen, the video container should move to the left so that the tracker does not disappear from view.
    const { currentPosition, setCurrentPosition } = useContext(EditorContext);
    const scrollContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const scrollContainer = scrollContainerRef.current;
       if (!scrollContainer) return;
        if (scrollContainer) {
          const rect = scrollContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
          const rightLimit = rect.width - 200;
          if (currentPosition > rightLimit) {
            scrollContainer.scrollBy({ left: 100, behavior: 'smooth' });
          }
        }
      }, [currentPosition]);

Currently the container only moves to the left when I pause the video and the tracker stops.

Try this code;
const { currentPosition, setCurrentPosition } = useContext(EditorContext);
const scrollContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const scrollContainer = scrollContainerRef.current;

  if (!scrollContainer) return;

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
    const scrollWidth = scrollContainer.scrollWidth;
    const containerWidth = scrollContainer.clientWidth;

    // Calculate the right edge of the visible area
    const rightLimit = scrollWidth - containerWidth;

    // Check if tracker is close to the right edge
    if (currentPosition > rightLimit - 100) {
      // Scroll by a fixed amount with smooth behavior
      scrollContainer.scrollBy({ left: 100, behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  };

  // Attach scroll event listener to the container
  scrollContainer.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

  // Clean up function to remove event listener on unmount
  return () => scrollContainer?.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
}, [scrollContainerRef]); // Dependency on scrollContainerRef



Didnt work((
I tried doing it differently, and it worked, but the timeline container scrolls once, and if you press pause, then play, it scrolls again
